# Given @record.record_items, how can you loop through record items and build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I have the following

List & ListItems

given @list, I want in the model, to loop through all the associated list_items as follows:

```
def update_items
    @list.list_items.each do |list_item|
      #inside
    end
  return items
end
```

Inside the loop I want to update each list_item but not save to the db. But pass a build record set to the controller to then save.

Is this possible somehow?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, and how does it fail? You can simply change the attributes of `list_item` without saving, and to an `object.build...` to build the objects. What else do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model `List`

```
def updated_list_items
     self.list_items.each do |list_item|
          # here you manipulate each item
     end
     self.list_items
end
```

Controller `ListsController`

```
@list_items = List.find(params[:id]).updated_list_items
```